# constexpr reference to a variable of an anonymous struct

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, unions, c++17

Given `struct B`, which inherits an anonymous `union` data member from `struct A`:

```
#include <cstddef>

struct A
{
    union
    {
        struct { int a, b, c; };
        int vals[3];
    };
};

struct B: A
{
    constexpr B(int x)
    :
        A{{{ x, x, x }}}
    {}

    constexpr int& operator[](size_t i)
    {
        return this->vals[i];
    }

    constexpr const int& operator[](size_t i) const
    {
        return this->vals[i];
    }
};
```

I declare a `constexpr` variable of type `B`, then calling its `operator[]` to assign the return value to a `constexpr int`:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr B b(7);
    constexpr int i = b[2];

    return 0;
}
```

However Clang 3.8 gives me the error message

```
constexpr variable 'i' must be initialized by a constant expression
```

The issue is related to the anonymous `union`, since when I simply use `int vals[3]` then everything works fine.

Is there a C++14 `constexpr` restriction I'm missing?

Comment: It's definitely union-related. gcc 5.3.1 croaks on the "A{ x, x, x }" initializer -- error: could not convert ‘x’ from ‘int’ to ‘A::<anonymous union>’

Comment: Interesting, Clang doesn't complain about the initalization. Does A violate the aggregate initialization rules?

Comment: Well, after tinkering around, if I give the union a formal field name: "union { ... } u;", and then declare an explicit constructor: "A(int aa, int bb, int cc) : u{aa, bb, cc}{}", gcc 5.3.1 accepts that part, but then has a major malfunction about the constexpr operator []s. "error: enclosing class of constexpr non-static member function ‘int& B::operator[](size_t)’ is not a literal type". I wasn't sure about this whole thing myself. Can't completely wrap my brain around a constexpr operator [], that does this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Don't know why but it looks like GCC sticks to A({x, x, x}) instead of A{x,x,x} or A{{x,x,x}}, so I updated my answer. However yeah, it does nothing with the original problem.

Comment: Ok, I futzed around with the code, and gcc 5.3.1 swallowed the whole thing. So, with appropriate beating, and torturing, gcc 5.3.1 will accept this. EDIT: just the declarations, gcc still has a problem with main().

Comment: gcc's error from the offending line in main() might offer more of a clue, here: error: accessing ‘A::<anonymous union>::vals’ member instead of initialized ‘A::<anonymous union>::<anonymous>’ member in constant expression

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, I'm also playing with it on https://gcc.godbolt.org with different compilers. That error message you refer gives some clue about that it is something with constexpr initialization, however it doesn't help much since you can't refer to an "<anonymous>" member.

Comment: constant expressions are not allowed to include undefined behaviour, however this code causes UB by accessing a member of a union that is not the same one that was last written to

Comment: Okay, Clang 3.8 on https://gcc.godbolt.org says: read of member 'vals' of union with active member '' is not allowed in a constant expression. @M.M is it a compiler bug then?

Comment: clang 3.8 seems correct to me

Comment: That clang 3.8 error is really saying the same thing that gcc's error says, actually...

Comment: compiler cannot decide should it interpret `A({x,x,x})` as `A() : a(x), b(x), y(x)` or as `A() : vals({x,x,x})`

Comment: @AndreiR. The compiler should decide it, because the C++ standard explicitly defines the initialization order of `union`s, see my answer below. The error came from the violation of the nested aggregate initialization. It should be `constexpr B(int x) : A{{{ x, x, x }}} {}`, because we dont just initialize `A`, since it has no user defined constructor. We initialize an aggregate `struct` inside an aggregate `union` inside the aggregate `A`. I updated the example code in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to M.M's answer, according to the [C++ union initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) rules the aggregate initializer always initializes the first union member only, which becomes the active member of that union.

So changing `A` to be `int vals[3]` the first declaration in the `union`:

```
struct A
{
    union
    {
        int vals[3];
        struct { int a, b, c; };
    };
};
```

or defining a constructor which initializes the member `int vals[3]` instead of the aggregate initialization which initializes the first `union` member:

```
struct A
{
    A(int a, int b, int c)
    : vals{ a, b c }
    {}

    union
    {
        struct { int a, b, c; };
        int vals[3];
    };
};
```

solves the problem of reading anonymous `union` member `int vals[3]` in a `constexpr` expression.

Answer (score 10):

This is not allowed:

```
constexpr int i = b[2];
```

`b[2]` is not a constant expression because it contains (ref: N4140 [expr.const]/2.8)

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) or modification (5.17, 5.2.6, 5.3.2) that is applied to a glvalue that refers to a non-active member of a union or a subobject thereof;

The active member of the union is the struct because you initialized that member.  The int array is inactive.

If you changed the `operator[]` function to `switch` and return a member of the struct instead, it should work.

*Note:* accessing the inactive member causes undefined behaviour.  Although common compilers support union aliasing as an extension,  it would avoid some trouble if you could design your code to not use union aliasing.

---

There are issues with the anonymous struct and its initializer too. Specifically, [class.union]/5:

> A union of the form `union { member-specification } ;` is called an *anonymous union*; it defines an unnamed object of unnamed type. The member-specification of an anonymous union shall only define non-static data members. [Note: Nested types, anonymous unions, and functions cannot be declared within an anonymous union. —end note ]

So you cannot have the anonymous struct inside the anonymous union. You need to make one of them non-anonymous. For example:

```
struct A
{
    struct AU { int a, b, c; };
    union
    {
        AU a;
        int vals[3];
    };
};
```

which works with the initializer `: A({x, x, x})`.  The inconsistent behaviour around the `A` initializer that you saw might be a gcc bug.

Comment: Anonymous structs in anonymous unions are pretty common, which is supported by all major compilers, so that's not an issue. I don't even notice the quoted standard stating that unnamed structs are not allowed in anonymous unions. It speaks about nested types, however an anomyous struct is not a type declaration.

Comment: @plasmacel I think it counts as a nested type . clang 3.8 gives a warning that it is an extension.

Comment: clang maybe warns you because it is a compiler extension, since strictly speaking as I know anonymous structs are not part of the C++ standard yet. They are however part of the C11 standard, and that's why all major C/C++ compilers support it from C++11 or earlier too.

Comment: In the meantime I figured out the initialization error. `A` should be initialized as `A{{{ x, x, x }}}`, because we dont just initialize `A`, since it has no user defined constructor. we initialize an aggregate `struct` inside an aggregate `union` inside the aggregate `A`.

Comment: "*The active member of the union is the struct because you initialized that member. The int array is inactive.*" Doesn't the common-initial-sequence rule make this moot?

Comment: @ildjarn This code doesn't have such a sequence ("If a standard-layout union contains two or more standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence,")

Comment: Ah, indeed; it seems a little critical thinking would have made _my question_ moot... ;-]